# How can i add a section of category image upload during adding of category in wp admin area?

Tags: images

can anyone please tell me? i want when i add a category then there to be a section to upload the category image ,i just uploading the image where i want the section it is denoted by circled area, if it is possible then please tell me:
[image]

and also i want this image at circled area after category and name to be above as 'category' or featured image to be show in this area,is it possible please reply me or if you have any solution then please guide me.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just a plugin based solution if you are not really digging deep: Use the acf plugin taxonomy field to extend the features:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Comment: i want to do that without plugins means that i want to use custom code for that ,can you  please tell me or if you have the reference about that code from where i can get help ,i search many time on google but not got specific code?

Comment: May be this can give you some ideas : https://pippinsplugins.com/adding-custom-meta-fields-to-taxonomies/